# Responsive image boundaries by parent of its parent?

Tags: html, css, image

I have responsive design where size of an image inside of a post depends on width of its container div ".postinner" inside of div ".postwrapper". 
Width of ".postwrapper" depends on width of a window and presence/absence of other elements of the site.

```css
.postwrapper {
  border: 1px solid #00f; 
  padding:5px;
}
.postinner {
  border: 1px solid #0f0; 
  max-width:10em; 
  padding:5px;
}
.postimage {
  max-width:100%; 
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="postwrapper">
  <div class="postinner">
    text text text text text text
    <img class="postimage" src="https://dummyimage.com/500x300/eb8d00/ffffff&text=image">
    text text text text text text
  </div>
</div>
```

My goal:
I want to limit width of ".postinner" by setting "max-width: 35em;" for better reading experience. 
At the same time I want make image size depend on the width of the responsive ".postwrapper" only. While image still inside of the container ".postinner". So image should ignore its container ".postinner" limits, and fit to limits of ".postwrapper" instead.

Is it possible to do with CSS only?

Note: 
Size of an image is different all the time.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0qs04p4/10/)

[visual expression of what I want to do (jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl74d.jpg)

Comment: Odd goal, have to say... and i am afraid that you will have to use js for it.

Comment: Anyway, you could try something like this, too: https://jsfiddle.net/g0qs04p4/11/ in connection for media queries - maybe it could lead to desired result?

Comment: sinisake thank you, its good idea with vw. It could work for someone. Though in my case that margin (40px in your jsfiddle example) is not constant. Site has left bar that some users hide, proportion of width ".postwrapper" to width of the window is changeable.

Answer (score 0):

I've just did this with jQuery, if you want this please take it , just Run code snippet , you can see there , the image width depends upon the `.postwrapper` width

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var widthMain = $('.postwrapper').width();
  $('.postimage').width(widthMain - 10);
});
```

```css
.postwrapper {
  border: 1px solid #00f;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50%;
}

.postinner {
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
  max-width: 10em;
  padding: 5px;
}

.postimage {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="postwrapper">
  <div class="postinner">
    text text text text text text
    <img class="postimage" src="https://dummyimage.com/500x300/eb8d00/ffffff&text=image"> text text text text text text
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried it, it works. Good solution. Though I'd like to avoid js for this if possible.